# Display component produced by function, replacing previous component on screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, radio-button

`showButtons(1)` displays the radio buttons for frame number 1, `showButtons(400)` displays the radio buttons for frame number 400.

This current code *displays all radio buttons for each frame up to 400* **BUT** I want one set of radio buttons displayed starting at frame 1 and to progressively change until reached frame number 400 replacing the previous radio buttons on the screen each time.

I can't seem to get it, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import React from "react";

const Test = (props)=> {

  const keys = props.test.map(frame => Object.keys(frame));
  const filteredKeys = keys.map(frame =>
    frame.filter(key => new RegExp(/^roi\d+$/).test(key))
  );
  if (filteredKeys.length === 0) return null;
  const showButtons = (frameNumber) => {
  return filteredKeys[frameNumber].map((roi, index) =>  (
      <div>
        <label for={`roi${frameNumber}`}>{`roi${index}`}</label>
        <input type="radio" id={`roi${frameNumber}`} />
       </div>
    ));
  };


    var answers = []
    for (var i = 1; i < 400; i++){
      answers.push(showButtons(i))
    }


  return (
    <div className="Test">
      <div>
    {answers}    
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Test;
```

Output.json file im working with in form:

```
[{"frame_number": 1, "roi0": [101.78202823559488, 99.39509279584912, 49.546951219239915, 29.728170731543948], "intensity0": 80.0, "roi1": [101.78202823559488, 99.39509279584912, 49.546951219239915, 29.728170731543948], "intensity1": 157.0},
{"frame_number": 2, "roi0": [102.56623228630755, 97.95906005049548, 50.25603182631066, 30.153619095786393], "intensity0": 80.0, "roi1": [102.56623228630755, 97.95906005049548, 50.25603182631066, 30.153619095786393], "intensity1": 158.0},
{"frame_number": 3, "roi0": [103.39336535376313, 98.20468223716023, 49.58465295946593, 29.750791775679556], "intensity0": 80.0, "roi1": [103.39336535376313, 98.20468223716023, 49.58465295946593, 29.750791775679556], "intensity1": 157.0},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print function each loop on to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60791251/print-function-each-loop-on-to-screen) basically the 3rd time you asked the same question, you also asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60793628/dynamically-update-the-current-radio-buttons-on-screen)

Comment: @HMR no answers, elaborated on the problem in a clearer way here. Does the post make more sense of what I want?

Comment: You also ignored all comments and answers and just reposted the same code. Do you want to a list of 400 checkboxes or 400 frames? Your code will produce 400 frames and your description says 400 frames so it's not clear what is wrong with the current code.

Comment: @HMR yes that's it, frames can have multiple radio buttons associated to it, not looking for a dispute simply have improved my question each time and this current question I think is explained well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try one last time based on your comments:

```js
const data = [
  {
    roi0: [], //never use these values in your code
    roi1: [],
  },
  {
    roi0: [],
    roi1: [],
    roi2: [],
  },
];
const Test = props => {
  const [currentFrame, setCurrentFrame] = React.useState(0);
  const frames = React.useMemo(() => {
    const keys = props.test.map(frame =>
      Object.keys(frame)
    );
    return keys.map(frame =>
      frame.filter(key => new RegExp(/^roi\d+$/).test(key))
    );
  }, [props.test]);
  const playing = currentFrame < frames.length - 1;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    const up = () => {
      setCurrentFrame(frame => frame + 1);
      timer = playing && setTimeout(up, 1000);
    };
    timer = playing && setTimeout(up, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [playing]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setCurrentFrame(0)}>
          reset
        </button>
      </div>
      {currentFrame >= frames.length
        ? null
        : frames[currentFrame].map((roi, index) => (
            <div key={roi}>
              <label>
                {`roi${index}`}
                <input type="radio" />
              </label>
            </div>
          ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test test={data} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that's very close to what i need thanks! However instead of selecting each frame, I need it to transfer into e.g frame 2 automatically after say 0.5 secs, so maybe a use of a timer is needed i'm not too sure. As it will be functioning alongside a video. Is this possible? thanks for your answer though